# How to handle 1st point of Seekbar in Android application using Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, appium-java

I'm automating an application form which has SeekBar for Age field and it has two points starting age and ending age. I already handle ending age point but I couldn't able to starting age point given in the attached below screenshot.

This is the below code that have implemented and that focus only on ending age point. I

xpath: `//android.widget.SeekBar[@content-desc='15%']`

**Code:**

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        int start = DistanceRangeSeekBaar.getLocation().getX();
        int end = DistanceRangeSeekBaar.getLocation().getY();       
        int moveTo = (int) (end * 0.4);
        actions.clickAndHold(DistanceRangeSeekBaar).moveToElement(DistanceRangeSeekBaar, start, moveTo).release().perform();
```

[image]